# php date from unix timestamp

Tags: php

I have a unix timestapm in my database and i want it to be formated like this:

```
Y-m-dTH:i:s
```

T is just a symbol between date and time. 
If I convert it like this:

```
$t_date=date("Y-m-dTH:i:s", $row['date']);
```

I get something like this: 2012-03-05UTC06:06:49. The problem is that T is one of the parameters for formating date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php

echo $t_date=date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", time());

?>
```

see http://codepad.org/SOSmzKvS

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP 5+, you can just use `date("c")` to get an ISO8601-format date (e.g. `2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00`).

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php